# Avoid redundant network call on Android device rotation using volley

Tags: java, android, networking, android-volley

I create a simple android app which just parse XML from apple website.
It has menu to parse top 10 "songs", "paid applications", or "free applications".

For network call, I use volley. Now, when I see the log when rotating device, processXml() -which fetch xml from URL and put it on list view- called multiple times, which in onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState(). IMHO, it might be redundant download.

My question :

1. am I put processXml() on a wrong place? If so, where is the correct place to avoid redundant network call?
2. since I use volley, is there any way to cache response and use it when device rotate? I think I've write the cache on VolleySingleton, but I don't know if my implementation is correct

Thanks a lot

Here is the log

```
// start of app
04-13 09:14:36.456 MainActivity: onCreate: processXml() called

// select "songs" from menu
04-13 09:14:49.627 MainActivity: onOptionsItemSelected: processXml() called

// rotate device
04-13 09:14:55.758 MainActivity: onCreate: processXml() called
```

Here is my source code on MainACtivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final String KEY_RSS_URL = "KEY_RSS_URL";
private static final String KEY_FEED_LIMIT = "KEY_FEED_LIMIT";
private String rssUrl = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=%d/xml";
private int feedLimit = 10;

private ListView xmlListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.xmlListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xmlListView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        this.rssUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_RSS_URL);
        this.feedLimit = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_FEED_LIMIT);
    }

    // need to put it here because when app start, it should already display top 10 free aps
    processRss(String.format(this.rssUrl, this.feedLimit));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  ... create menu
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.mnuFree:
            this.rssUrl = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=%d/xml";
            break;
        case R.id.mnuPaid:
            this.rssUrl = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=%d/xml";
            break;
        case R.id.mnuSongs:
            this.rssUrl = "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=%d/xml";
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    processRss(String.format(this.rssUrl, this.feedLimit));
    Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: processRss() called");

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString(KEY_RSS_URL, this.rssUrl);
    outState.putInt(KEY_FEED_LIMIT, this.feedLimit);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    this.rssUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_RSS_URL);
    this.feedLimit = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_FEED_LIMIT);

    processRss(String.format(this.rssUrl, this.feedLimit));
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: processRss() called");
}

private void processRss(String rssUrl) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, rssUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ParseApplication parseApplication = new ParseApplication();
            if (parseApplication.parse(response)) {
                ArrayAdapter<FeedEntry> arrayAdapter = new FeedAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_record,
                        parseApplication.getApplications(),
                        VolleySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getImageLoader());

                xmlListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: from volley : " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

}

For the VolleySingleton, I use this code,with getRequestQueue using cache

public class VolleySingleton {

```
private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
private static Context mCtx;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        File cacheDir = new File(mCtx.getCacheDir(), "VOLLEY_CACHE_DIR");
        mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(
                new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir, 512 * 512),
                new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));

        mRequestQueue.start();
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> 1. am I put processXml() on a wrong place? If so, where is the correct place to avoid redundant network call?

Yes, you are calling that method in two places. Instead of repeating the same call in `onRestoreInstanceState`, you should keep a reference to the ongoing request. There are several ways to do that. Some of them are:

- use [getLastNonConfigurationInstance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance())
- use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and broadcast the network response to your Activity (http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/)
- use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) (https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832)

> 2. since I use volley, is there any way to cache response and use it when device rotate? I think I've write the cache on VolleySingleton,
>      but I don't know if my implementation is correct

You are using a `DiskBasedCache` and it looks the same as the example in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html). You can easily check if it is working by turning off the network connection (data & wifi) and rotating your device. You can also check the Volley code to know how does it uses the cache.